# Small, inexpensive microcontroller capable of high speed SSP?

Tags: microcontroller

I'm looking for a small microcontroller that can accept high speed serial data. [NXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NXP_Semiconductors#See_also) calls it an SSP peripheral -- it works with an SPI, [Microwire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwire) or [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_Serial_Interface) bus, and I'm using it in a 32-bit SSI application. By small I mean both physically (under 50 pins) and in terms of RAM/Flash (the 8 KB RAM and 32 KB Flash is more than enough). High-speed means working as an SSI slave with clocks up to about 50 MHz or so.

I'm currently using an [LPC2103](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NXP_LPC#LPC2000_series), and it performs pretty well up to about 2-3 MHz as an SSI slave, but I can only see the first 16 bits of the 32-bit word. I'm using both the SSP and SSI peripheral to grab all 32-bits, but that's a real kludge and for the next version I'm hoping to do away with the speed limitation and word length barrier.

As far as architecture goes... it's really open. The LPC's ARM7TDMI of course, but [PIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontroller) or [AVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR) would work just fine, I'm not tied to any particular architecture and have worked with practically all of them at one point or another. I'd even looked at a small [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array) chip, but it's also near impossible to find a low pin-count FPGA with a large number of programmable logic.

Comment: Why does it need to be so fast? Are you pushing a constant stream of data at 50MHz? Or just occasional blips of data with idle periods in between? Because if it's a large stream of data, your MCU will need to be fast enough to handle the data as well.

Comment: How flexible is your architecture? Even if (when) you find a micro that can do 50MHz SPI/SSI/SSP/4-Wire/etc., you're likely to have trouble with issues of DC bias, coupled noise, and EMI.  Have you considered (1) serial LVDS, if the number of wires are an issue or (2) parallel data?

Comment: Also, why are you having trouble with the word length?  Just because the device has a byte-oriented peripherial doesn't mean that you can't stuff into a 4-byte data structure.  Takes a little more work in your interrupt, but it doesn't have to be a kludge.

Comment: The actual distance traveled is pretty small, and the device furthest from the source of the data is a little serial DAC; its maximum clock rate is 50MHz and with some of the data I'm pushing I come close to that rate, which is why I'm trying to find a microcontroller with a slave SSP interface that can handle it. I had looked at LVDS but it just wasn't necessary.

Comment: As far as word length goes -- I only have one frame sync pulse every 32 bits, and I've found that the SSP interfaces will not pick up a second serial word unless there's a frame sync pulse to tell them to do so. I'm currently using a kludge with some external hardware to synthesize a second frame sync pulse 16 clocks later, and have also used two SSP ports with the interrupt of one generating a sync pulse for the second... It's just something I'd rather avoid if I can.

Comment: It's a constant stream of data feeding a quad DAC. The microcontroller monitors the bus for control words to actuate some I/O synchronously to the data stream, with the eventual goal of being able to provide status and other information back to the master over the same 4-wire bus.

Answer (score 5):

An [XMOS chip](http://www.xmos.com/) can easily manage 50 MHz SPI in software, the I/Os can handle 100 MHz events. A CPLD such as the Altera MAX II could also be used with a PIC or AVR. They are available in small 44-lead packages but development would be harder.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The XMOS devices are certainly higher end than the devices I've been using to date. They've also got free development tools for my preferred environment (Linux). I'm going to take a closer look at these devices, thank you!

Comment: While XMOS chips are great, to take advantage of their parallel computing capabilities, you have to learn their proprietary version of C which extends upon it with parallel functions.  I myself have worked with them and it isn't too bad its just you can't use it anywhere else

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to find a 50MHz serial port on a PIC or an AVR as far as I know.

My guess is you'd need to look at something on the order of a cortex-A8 SoC to get peripherals that fast.

Why not slow down the baud rate generator on the master when talking to this slow device?

Comment: I don't think you need to go as high as an A8 for 50MHz - That's 600MHz+ iPad/Droid territory.  Cortex M3 parts clock in at around 100MHz, and the ARM7TDMI mentioned in the question can probably do it as well, clocking 60-70MHz.

Comment: Its not a matter of doing it, its a matter of finding a production SoC with the capability, which i highly doubt is out there...why would a 100mhz core clocked SoC need a 50Mhz SSI bus?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't slow the data down; I'm driving a quad serial DAC and the microcontroller I'm trying to put on the bus is being used to drive some related I/O synchronous to the data being pushed out the DACs.  The ARMv4 devices I'm using (LPC21xx) can do a 35MHz SPI clock when in master mode without any trouble whatsoever, so I think that I might be able to hit 50 with a slightly beefier device.  SoCs are similar to FPGAs though; it's proving difficult to find low pin count devices with large amounts of configurable logic.

Comment: generally a SoC will run faster in master mode than it will slave.  The processes of extracting the clock as the slave has to do usually isn't something you can do near your system clock rate.  Also isn't SSI single master single slave? how are you snooping on the data line to the DAC's? and how is the bus terminated?

Answer (score 1):

This might be one of the niches where a PSoC would fit.

If I were you, I would ask the people at the PSoC forums http://www.psocdeveloper.com/forum/
: "Can the PSoC digital peripherals can be configured to emulate a 32-bit SPI/SSP slave at 50 MHz?"
I see that some people have already programmed a Cypress ARM Cortex PSoC device to emulate a 16-bit SPI slave at 33 Mbit/s.
http://www.cypress.com/?docID=37034
I suspect 32-bits would be easy on a PSoC; perhaps even 50 MHz.
(Some Cypress PSoC ARM Cortex chips are rated at 80 MHz).

50 MHz as a SPI/SSP slave is pretty difficult.
I see that one SPI debugging tool can only listen to SPI traffic (more or less as a slave) at 25 MHz --
although it can drive the SPI bus at 50 MHz (as master).
http://www.byteparadigm.com/kb/article/AA-00701/0/What-is-the-maximum-frequency-of-SPI-Xpress.html
Another SPI debugging tool apparently can listen to 100 MHz SPI traffic.
http://support.saleae.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200362675-BBB-Arduino-RasPi
Even hard-wired logic, using something like the 74HC4094 or 74HC595,
their datasheets claim the chip can "typically" go 50 MHz but it's not guaranteed.

You may be forced to use a CPLD or FPGA to handle this fire-hose of data.

Answer (score 0):

Several years have passed. **STM32H750** seems good enough,

https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h750-value-line.html

- Core Speed: 480MHz
- SPI SCK: ≥ 100MHz for both master and slave
- Price (budgetary): $3.37

I have considered XMOS. It is perfectly a good match for my requirement but not massively available due to its high price.

Comment: This ancient question would not be permitted if it were posted today, as questions seeking purchase recommendations were long ago banned.

Comment: I am actually searching for a better option than this MCU from ST